# Strategies for Cassandra backups

Tags: cassandra, hdfs

We are considering additional backup strategies for our Cassandra database.

Currently we use:

- nodetool snapshot - allows us to take a snapshot of all data on a given node at any time
- replication level in itself is a backup - if any node ever goes down we still have additional copies of the data

Is there any other efficient strategy? The biggest issue is that we need a copy of life data in additional datacenter, which has just one server. So, for example let's say we 3 Cassandra servers, that we want to replicate to one backup Cassandra server in a second datacenter. the only way I can think we can do it is to set the replication level to 4. That means all the data will have to be written to all servers at all times.

We are also considering running Cassandra on top of some network distributed system like HDFS. Correct me if I'm wrong but that would be a very inefficient use of Cassandra?

Are there any other efficient backup strategies for Cassandra that can backup the current data without impairing it's performance?